# Sticky element change color on specific position

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want the sticky element to change its color in a certain place and then return the color back. That is, initially it is orange, on block 2 it is green, and on block 3 it is again orange. I will post code on jsfiddle because there are a lot of code and some problems with jquery : https://jsfiddle.net/5pn0t41g/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
/* Фиксация меню при прокрутке */
$('.header-menu-wrp')
    .addClass('original')
    .clone()
    .insertAfter('.header-menu-wrp')
    .addClass('cloned')
    .removeClass('original');

function resizeMenu(){
    var $original = $('.header-menu-wrp.original');
    var $cloned = $('.header-menu-wrp.cloned');
    
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= ($original.offset().top)){    
        $cloned.css({
            'top': 0, 
            'width': $original.css('width'), 
            'display': 'block',
            'left': $original.offset().left+'px'
        });
        $original.css('visibility', 'hidden');
    } else {
        $cloned.css('display', 'none');
        $original.css('visibility', 'visible');
    }
}

$(window).scroll(function(){
    resizeMenu();
});

$(window).resize(function(){
    resizeMenu();   
});

/* Выделение активных пунктов меню */
var last_id;
var $top_menu = $('.header-menu-wrp.cloned');
var menu_height = $top_menu.outerHeight(true);
var $menu_items = $top_menu.find('a');
var $scroll_items = $menu_items.map(function(){
    var item = $($(this).attr('href'));
    if (item.length){
        return item;
    }
});

$menu_items.click(function(e){
    var href = $(this).attr('href'),
    offset_top = href === '#' ? 0 : $(href).offset().top - menu_height;
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: offset_top
    }, 300);
    e.preventDefault();
});

$(window).scroll(function(){
    var from_top = $(this).scrollTop() + menu_height;
    var mar = parseInt($top_menu.css('margin-bottom'));
    var cur = $scroll_items.map(function(){
        if ($(this).offset().top < from_top + mar){
            return this;
        }
    });
    cur = cur[cur.length - 1];
    var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : '';
    if (last_id !== id){
        last_id = id;
        $menu_items.parent()
            .removeClass('active')
            .end()
            .filter("[href='#" + id + "']")
            .parent()
            .addClass('active');
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Please [edit] and include the necessary code to reproduce the issue **right within** your Question. Read [ask]

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Sorry,added code. I forgot to click save on site, also added only jsquery here cause of a lot of code.

Comment: `(document)` ... you mean... `$(document)` ?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan yes. Fiixed, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the desired color (or some kind of flag) to each menu element and change colors based on it.

Here is the example for setting green color on the second block based on the `menu-color` attribute. You can move colors into the css and change the menu-styles in the same way by adjusting the class value..

HTML:

```
<div class="header-menu-wrp">
    <div class="wrp">
        <div class="header-menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#block-1">Блок 1</a></li>
                <li menu-color="green"><a href="#block-2">Блок 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#block-3">Блок 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#block-4">Блок 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
        var from_top = $(this).scrollTop() + menu_height;
        var mar = parseInt($top_menu.css('margin-bottom'));
        var cur = $scroll_items.map(function(){
            if ($(this).offset().top < from_top + mar){
                return this;
            }
        });
        cur = cur[cur.length - 1];
        var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : '';
        if (last_id !== id){
            last_id = id;

            // store the menu-block into the var
            let adjustedEl = $menu_items.parent()
                .removeClass('active')
                .end()
                .filter("[href='#" + id + "']")
                .parent()
                .addClass('active');
        
            let setColor = '';
            // set the menu color base on the adjustedEl's menu-color attribute
            if ( adjustedEl.attr('menu-color') )
                    setColor = adjustedEl.attr('menu-color');
        
            adjustedEl.closest('.header-menu-wrp').css('background-color', setColor);
         }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, its an option.